# How to make an element display over another element when z-index doesn't work?

Tags: html, css, z-index

[image: Picture of what's happening]

[Site URL](https://craze-rpg.com/index.php)

I'm using the Bootstrap 4 nav bar collapse functionality for my site. What I would like is either:

1. Expanding the nav bar pushes down all content below it
2. Expanding the nav bar covers all content below it

I've tried using z-index with no luck. What other options do I have?

```css
.navbar-collapse {
  display: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<header id="header">
 <div id="hero">
  <nav class="navbar">
  <a class="logo navbar-brand" href="https://craze-rpg.com/index.php">Craze RPG</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-dark bg-dark" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
   <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse bg-dark" id="navbarSupportedContent">
   <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
    <li class="nav-item active">
     <a class="nav-link" href="/guidebook.php">Guidebook</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
     <a class="nav-link" href="#">Face Claim</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
     <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
     <a class="nav-link" href="#">Advertise &amp; Affiliate</a>
    </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
 </nav>
  
 </div>
</header>
<div class="wrapper">
 <!-- Welcome back -->
    <!-- start: header_welcomeblock_member -->
<ul class="nav justify-content-end">
 <li class="nav-item">
  <!-- start: header_welcomeblock_member_user -->
<a class="nav-link hvr-float" href="https://craze-rpg.com/usercp.php" class="usercp"><i class="fas fa-user fa-2x" title="My Account"></i></a>
<!-- end: header_welcomeblock_member_user -->
 </li>
 <li class="nav-item">
  
 </li>
 <li class="nav-item">
  
 </li>
 <li class="nav-item">
  <!-- start: header_welcomeblock_member_pms -->
<a class="nav-link hvr-float" href="https://craze-rpg.com/private.php"><i class="fas fa-envelope fa-2x" title="Private Messages"></i></a>
<!-- end: header_welcomeblock_member_pms -->
 </li>
</ul>
<br class="clear">
<span class="welcome"><strong>Welcome back, <a href="https://craze-rpg.com/member.php?action=profile&amp;uid=2">Sinestra</a></strong>. <a href="https://craze-rpg.com/member.php?action=logout&amp;logoutkey=676a897231d2d9e681399958d3972e6e" class="logout hvr-icon-forward">Log Out <i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right hvr-icon"></i></a></span>
</div>
<!-- end: header_welcomeblock_member -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cases like that, where z-index does not help to make an element appear overlapping on another element, you have to take that element out of its natural flow.

You can do that by using `position: absolute;` or `position: relative;` on the element which should overlap other elements.

**Edit**
However, it seems that the element with id *#hero* has a clip-path property, which cuts off your element. So it might not be an issue of z-index but rather of the clip-path property.

If thats the case, unfortunately [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44154783/prevent-css-clip-path-from-clipping-children) does not provide a solution to prevent clip-path to be inherited by children.

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply `z-index` at the proper parent level in order to work. To work efficiently with `z-index` one needs to understand [stacking contexts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context).

The key to it lies into:

> *Stacking contexts are treated atomically as a single unit in the parent stacking context.*

In other words, your menu is part of a stacking context placed below the content of your page. You need to change the `z-index` of that stacking context. Practically, you need:

```css
#header { z-index: 2; }
```

**Note:** if it doesn't work, you need to allow `#header` to create a stacking-context, using any of the cases outlined on MDN (linked above). The simplest solution is to give `#header` a `position` value other than `static` (default).
If you need `position:static` on `#header`, alternatives are to give it `transform: translateX(0);` or [`isolation:isolate;`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/i/isolation/).